# How can I add effects to sound going into my mic live on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, streaming, microphone

I'm wondering if there is software out there that I can use to edit the sounds going into my mic that will change the way my voice sounds. Preferably live since I want to stream to Skype and Google Hangout.

Comment: How exactly do you want your voice to sound?

Comment: I want it to sound a bit different, like lower/higher tone depending on some events.